# Precise start and end time of subscription cycle in Stripe (with case of February)

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a web product, we offer monthly subscription. I would like to simulate how Stripe calculates the start and end time (i.e., [current_period_start](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_start) and [current_period_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_end)) of a monthly subscription.

For instance, we have a subscription (`sub_1OeNBaKr7t8UXDrfehajJVWA`) created on `2024-01-30T19:41:34`. Today is `2024-02-04`. We can see in the system that the current cycle starts from `2024-01-30T19:41:34` and ends on `2024-02-29T19:41:34`.

I would like to know what should be the start of the next cycle. Will it start from `2024-02-29T19:41:34` or `2024-03-01T00:00:00` or something else?

Here is some doc: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the next billing cycle will start at the subscription's [current_period_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_end) (i.e., 2024-02-29T19:41:34).

You can use [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) to test your billing integration and get a better understanding on how it works.